# SharePoint 2010 Workflow Allow to Start if all Parameters are True

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I'm working on creating an approval workflow inside of SharePoint. I'm using the approval workflow for a document library. I have a Yes/No check box that is used to tell the workflow to start the approval process or not. I want the workflow to be able to start when the document is created or updated. That way the user does not have to to go to Workflows > Start Workflow. The problem that I'm having is that the workflow starts as soon as it gets created and does not update properly. I have to go in and terminate the workflow. After the workflow is terminated and the check box equals yes, it will send off the approval email. I'm using Stop Workflow if the check box equals no. Is there something that I'm missing? I do not want the workflow to start in any way unless the check box equals yes. Is there a way to terminate the workflow if the check box equals no? Let me know if there is any other information I need to provide.

If check box = No then do not start the approval process and stop workflow / do not start

If the check box = Yes then start the approval process

Answer (score 0):

You can not set condition for automatically started workflow OOB. In your own workflow you can do test at the beginning of workflow and either continue or finish it. If it's not possible to modify the workflow create new one. Do tests in the beginning and run original workflow using InvokeWorkflow activity accordingly.